# can't include javascript in included php

Tags: javascript, php, include

I have a main index.php and it has an external js included.
The navigation in my site is always stays in index and including the relevant php file.
I also have a js file that i want it to only affect a certain php file (if i include it in the index.php it affects all the php files).
when i try to include in a file called 'welcome.php'
it doesn't work. The js is right because i tried putting the code in the index.php and it worked.

this is how i included it in 'welcome.php'

```
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../js/content.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: this is how i included it in 'welcome.php'..... How ?? You have shown us html codes and not php

Comment: I am not sure how you determine to include welcome.php file, try to use same statement to include the js file. Need more info for more suggestions. If same statement not possible to repeat, declare a variable inside the statement and on head or where u want to add the file, use if variable is isset, echo the file.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  When you load the welcom.php page with a JavaScript console open, what do you see?

Comment: the path is probably different in welcome.php than in index.php. are the files in the same folder? my guess is not so `../js/content.js` is going up a level then down into js folder.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear. 
except for the index.php, all my php files contain only html.
when i say it doesn't work i mean that the page is loading but the js script is not executing.
i fixed the path and i'm sure it's right.

When i try to include the js file in welcome.php with the line in my first post, the js script is not executing. If i write my js code directly to welcome.php(in script tags) in welcome.php , it runs perfect.
hope i'm clear this time.

Comment: You should be able to determine why that is by using your browser dev tools. Is the script tag there? Is it giving a 404 because the url is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

### Edited due to above comments

if it's working when you type it in directly but not when echo'ing it then it's because you're not escaping qoutes correctly

try

```
  <script src=\"../js/content.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
```